# pthread and condition variable

Tags: pthreads, conditional-statements

I'm wondering why the following code gives unexpected output: `a` can get 110...!

```
pthread_t th[nbT];
void * func(void *d)
{       
    while(a<100)
    {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&l);
            cout <<a <<" in thread "<<pthread_self()<<"\n";
            a+=1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&l);
    }  
    return NULL;
 } 
  int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
 {
    for(int i=0;i<nbT;i++)
            pthread_create(&(th[i]), NULL, func, NULL);

    for(int i=0;i<nbT;i++)
            pthread_join(th[i],NULL);
 }
```

Comment: should I use wait on condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you get the lock (mutex) *after* checking the condition, so you don't know if it's still true or not once you get the lock. You should just do a simple double-check:

```cpp
while(a<100)
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&l);
        cout <<a <<" in thread "<<pthread_self()<<"\n";
        if (a<100) a+=1; // <== Added condition here!
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&l);
}
```